# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'

Tags: python, attributeerror

```js
image = driver.find_elementby_css_selector('#Sva75c > div.ZuT88e > div > div.dFMRD > div.pxAole > div.tvh9oe.BIB1wf > c-wiz > div.nIWXKc.JgfpDb > div.OUZ5W > div.zjoqD > div.qdnLaf.isv-id.b0vFpe > div > a > img')
```

As a beginner, I tried to follow the instructions in the book, but I got an error. Help

Comment: If this is related to Selenium, add an appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a typo - maybe you meant to use `find_element_by_css_selector`?